# PHP to create MySQL query from URL query

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I have a relatively small search form that I want people to use to search my SQL database.

The only way I've done this before was with a billion nested if statements. Is there a better way to do this?

I am parsing my URL query string, so I have my variables of say:

```
$city
$bedrooms
$elementaryschool
```

If I were to just try to try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE ";

if(isset($city)) {
    $sql .= " `City` LIKE " . $city;
}
if(isset($bedrooms)) {
    $sql .= " AND `Bedrooms` >= " . $bedrooms;
}
if(isset($elementaryschool)) {
    $sql .= " AND `ElementarySchool` = " . $elementaryschool;
}
```

Then I run into an issue when $city isn't set because my query ends up with "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE AND `Bedrooms` >= $bedrooms"

That wouldn't exactly work. What are my options?

I completely understand how to do it if I am including all parameters in my query, which seems to be what all previous questions have asked. But how do I do this when not all fields will have a value? I have a total of 12 possible fields to use for searching, and they can search by just 1 or by all 12.

As I mentioned before, all of the questions I have been able to find refer to coming up with one static SQL query, instead of one that will have varying number of parameters.

Comment: Agree this question is not a duplicate (at least of the quotes/ticks link), I will help you if it is reopened. In the mean time, please read up on [PDO and prepared statements with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496). Using user input directly in query string concatenation can leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
$where = array();
$params = array();
```

and then:

```
if(isset($city)) {
    $where[] = "City LIKE ?";
    $params[] = $city;
}

if(isset($bedrooms)) {
    $where[] = "Bedrooms >= ?";
    $params[] = $bedrooms;
}

if(isset($elementaryschool)) {
    $where[] = "ElementarySchool = ?";
    $params[] = $elementaryschool;
}
```

and finally:

```
if(!empty($where)) {
    $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
}

$result = $db->prepare($sql)->execute($params);
```

PLEASE NOTE that here, since I do not know what kind of database layer/abstraction you are using, `$db` represents the database connection, `prepare()` is used to create a prepared statement, and `execute()` tu run it, as you would do using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php); this also protects against SQL injection.

Comment: This makes sense and is very similar to what I had rigged. I am trying to implement PDO now, to be secure... Fingers crossed. Thanks so much for your input!